# smtp connection is failing using javamail api?

Tags: jakarta-mail

whenever i am trying to connect to smtp host it shows connection failed with response -1 on port 25 on my local exchange server, but i am able to connect to gmail smtp host to send emails from gmail i am using below code.

```
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localexchange.server.address");
        props.put("mail.from", "emailid");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom();
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                              "emailid");
            msg.setSubject("JavaMail hello world example");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText("Hello, world!\n");
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + mex);
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  Did you try them?

Comment: yes i tried them, i think mails are not getting routed to my exchange server but i am able to do telnet to my exchange server successfully, is there any way i can tell my program to route like TTL(time to live) for my mail.

Comment: i found that LAN which i am connected to is in different network and exchange is in different network both networks are connected through switch.(my outlook works perfect with same exchange)

Comment: If you're running telnet on the same machine that your JavaMail application is running on, and telnet connects but JavaMail doesn't, I have no idea what's going on.  Possibly you have a firewall on your machine that only allows certain applications to connect to certain remote machines?  And if you're comparing with Outlook, note that Outlook often uses a Microsoft proprietary protocol instead of the internet standard protocols that JavaMail uses.  Make sure your Exchange server is set up to support those internet standard protocols.

Comment: hi everyone i want to know if in case esmtp is used then how to send mail through javamail i mean which settings i need to change

Comment: Which ESMTP feature do you want to use?

Comment: i have ESMTP server to send email i want to send email through it using javamail and i am able to telnet ESMTP server but not able to send mails using smtps in above code.

Comment: ESMTP is "Extended SMTP" - a way to extend SMTP with additional fetures.  It builds on the base SMTP protocol.  JavaMail supports some of the ESMTP extensions.  In any event, we're going to need more details than "it doesn't work".  Try the debugging tips in the JavaMail FAQ and report on exactly what you tried and exactly what results you got.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Bill Shannon i will come back with exact errors i am getting.

Answer (score 0):

first check whether your SMTP server port is open for your system.

You can check this by Telnet command

Windows---start----run----cmd---type 'Telnet (SMTP SERVER IP) (PORT)'
Hit enter

Answer (score 0):

Get the actual SMTP session debug text by setting the `mail.smtp.debug` property to `true`. You can either read the debug output from the command prompt or set it to output to a file.

Check if your method of authentication is allowed. After it says `AUTH` it should have the permitted authentication options (GSSAPI, DIGEST-MD5, PLAIN, LOGIN).

If it doesn't get to `AUTH` you might be using the wrong port. Usually:

- 25 for SMTP
- 465 for SSL
- 587 for TLS

If you post the debug output, we can probably offer some more tips.