# how to make html <img> tag revolving effect?

Tags: javascript, html, image

i have images which are moving to right of screen, i want to add revolving effect to them but.
it should be like when one image goes out of browser space then it should come back from other side of browser. not after whole image lefts or should not go out side browser space by extending horizontal scrollbar.
is it possible with  tag?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are trying to do? Maybe another site you saw the effect on?

Comment: Seems like I have to ask: what have you tried? Hint: It's not possible with only HTML.

Comment: @bažmegakapa it is with CSS3, actually :P

Comment: @Ozzy So that is HTML? I don't see anything about CSS.

Comment: @Ozzy No he still needs to detect the screen width to make it work. So javascript.

Comment: @Hindol No he can use % element positions to make it work within the screen.

Comment: i want effect like .gif images have repeat itself so fast.

Comment: @KingCronus : can you please provide solution to this i will accept it if its correct.    ""http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407312/how-to-add-text-to-facebook-news-feed-through-facebook-apps"" and to this as well ""http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296660/smtp-connection-is-failing-using-javamail-api"" remember it should work and not any garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might find this useful

[animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html)

Another example that you can follow is :

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

Comment: i want revolving images and not rotating.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want on someone elses site? IDK what the difference is between revolving and rotating...

Comment: @KingCronus rotating is rotating around itself and revolving means revolving around something, eg:- earth rotates around itself and revolves around sun.

Comment: what you can do is use the jquery animate function, in that you can put in a loop where you change the top and left attributes and the z-index of the image based on a circular equation

Comment: yes thats solution @ArohaLabs thanks

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not make this possible for you. It is a markup language and has nothing to do with presentation or behaviour.

To create something you describe, you will need Javascript. You should invest a great amount of time into learning it, and when you feel ready, you should attempt to write your "image revolving script". Then you will encounter problems, and the StackOverflow community will be happy to help.